# How do i target specific data values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have assigned data attributes to every grid class, each value is a different number ranging from 1-64.

I want it so that it adds a class 'success' to the grid class with a data-value="1", i can only get it without the specific value. so it finds all data attributes called data value and adds the success class but I cant figure out how to only add it to classes with the data attribute of 1.

```
function clickSquare() {
$('.grid').click(function(){

    if ( $('.grid').data('value'))
    {
        $(this).addClass("success");

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("error");
    }

    });
}


<div data-value="1" class="grid pointer">1</div>
```

also, if i set up an array

```
var values = ['1', '2']
```

how could i do it so that the jquery only attaches the class to values with that of the array. hope that made sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` inside the event handler to refer to the clicked `grid` element. If you use the selector `.grid` inside the handler it will return the data value of the first `grid` element in the page instead of current element

```
    $('.grid').click(function () {
        if ($(this).data('value') == 1) {
            $(this).addClass("success");

        } else {
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }

    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Gxrm/)

Comment: @arunPJohny but that would target all classes with a data attribute of value, not with ones with a data-value="1"

Comment: @AlexNewman you need to test the data value against the desired value like `$(this).data('value')) == 1`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Okay that works, but how do i now make it select the variable? So i want it to select the values that have the numbers in my array variable

Comment: @AlexNewman what do you mean by array variable and what numbers?

Comment: @AlexNewman in the above case you want to add the class `success` to elements with `data-value` 1 and 2 others class `error` needs to be added, whether my understanding is correct

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want it so that the class can be added to multiple elements, so for example. you click data value 8 and it adds success, you click data value 6 and it adds success, you click data value 64 and it adds success. So I made an array with multiple numbers and i want it so that "when any of these numbers are clicked  display success class on that element"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36550/discussion-between-alex-newman-and-arun-p-johny)